# magento 2 how to display the category product in homepage?

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

```
 <p>{{block type="catalog/product_list" 
           column_count="4" 
           category_id="13" 
           template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}</p>
```

I have used the above code in magento version 1.x to display the category products in the home page

After updating to Magento version 2.0., the above code doesn't work anymore.

How can I rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

```html
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList"
         products_count="4" 
        template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml"
        conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;    s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`
            value`;s:1:`13`;]]"}}
```

in the above code last line, 13 represents the category id
change the category_id as you need

Answer (score 0):

Try this

{{block type="core/template" column_count="4" category_id="13" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

after that go to yourtheme/catalog/product/list.phtml and then something try to print or echo at the top of this file

Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

```html
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList"
         products_count="4" 
        template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml"
        conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;    s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`
            value`;s:1:`13`;]]"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<p>{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" title="CTlog" show_pager="1" products_per_page="5" products_count="10" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:1:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]]" page_var_name="pmqabw"}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this

```html
<?php
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');
$priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); 
$productmodel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct'); 
?>
<div class="worldcup-deals">
                <div class="deals-baaner">
                    <img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/worldcup/2.png'); ?>' alt="deal-banner">
                </div>
                <div class="deals-products">
                    <div class="category-product-listing-world">
                        <?php 
                        $bestsamrtphoneid = 6685; 
                        $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($bestsamrtphoneid);
                        $samrtphonecategoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                        $samrtphonecategoryProducts->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
                        $samrtphonecategoryProducts->getSelect()->limit(8);
                        //->setPageSize(8) // only get 10 products 
                        //->setCurPage(1);
                        ?>
                        <?php foreach ($samrtphonecategoryProducts as $product) { ?>
                        <div class="product-listing-world-item">
                            <?php 
                            $imagehelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
                            $image = $imagehelper->init($product,'category_page_list')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(300, 300)->getUrl();
                            ?>
                            <div class="inner-world-wrap">
                                <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
                                </a>
                                <h3 class="product-name">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                                        <?php echo $product->getName() ?>
                                    </a>
                                </h3>
                                <?php echo $productmodel->getProductPrice($product);?>

                                <div class="shop-new">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                                        <?php echo __('Shop now >'); ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/demo/demo.png'); ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>  
                    <a class="view" href="https://avechi.com/wakilisha-world-cup/cool-phones.html" target="_blank">view more >></a>
                </div>                       
            </div>
```